# Multiple RIA Service Library Issue with Prism 4.1 and Silverlight 5

Tags: wcf, silverlight, telerik, visual-studio-2013, devart

My Prism 4.1 , Silverlight 5 Application have connectivity with oracle 11g via DevArt Oracle connector. My controls will be of Telerik
I've used EnitityFramwork 6 Database 1st Approach. Entitites & Context are in 1 c# project under Data module.

I'm unable to create (OpenRIA)RIA Domain Service library in my Prism project. It doesn't allow me to choose entitites from wizard. Means it doesn't show me the Entitites in wizard.

## ITS OPENRIA with VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

RIA Services Domain Services no longer exists as a wizard within Vs2013:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2013/10/25/who-moved-my-cheese-ria-services.aspx

You instead have access to some NuGet packages, and the [Open RIA Services project](http://www.openriaservices.net/)

Comment: Mashton I created Open RIA Project only. I that I'm getting this issue.